# Fake being a browser to avoid a 403 error

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to connect to a webpage and scrape data from it, but it's giving me an HTTP 403 response (unlike my browser, which loads it successfully). From what I understand, I have to make my scraper pretend that it's a browser. I've tried two things: setting the user agent to be a browser, and setting the referrer to be the same website (both of these I got by browsing StackOverflow). I still, however, get a 403. My code looks like this (I know the browser is old, I just copypasted it, surely it shouldn't matter?):

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.website.com/subpage/")
            .userAgent("\"User-Agent\", \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11\"")
            .referrer("http://www.website.com")
            .get();
```

What else do I need to do to trick the server into thinking that I'm a browser?

Comment: Can you give us the link? Your Code isn't wrong. I thinks its a cookie which is missing. Do you call the page with https in your bowser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you can load the page successfully(a 200?) with your browser, you can use that information to create a Jsoup connection.

Open up your browser's network tab in development view, have a look at the request and imitate it. For example, a GET to this page looks like

```
Host: stackoverflow.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0)
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript; q=0.01
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134906/fake-being-a-browser-to-avoid-a-403-error
Content-Length: 263
Cookie: x; prov=x; acct=t=wx
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

All these have corresponding Jsoup methods. This should be enough to fool the web server.

If you are still experiencing trouble you should log the actual request to see it is sent as is expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to distinguish web browsers from robot user agents. One possibility that comes to mind is checking for the Accept header content.
I suggest that you use Firefox developer tools to inspect your requests and add headers/cookies to your scraper application.
Additionally you can use a packet sniffer (ngrep, wireshark) and compare your requests with the requests of a real browser session to determine what signals are used.

Answer (score 0):

A web server may return a **403 Forbidden HTTP status code** in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. Status code 403 responses are the result of the **web server being configured to deny access**, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.

> It is working in browser, in browser he might take some header or
>   cookies.

Please check which are the header or any other param require using **Fiddler** or simple browser & set those value in `Jsoup` it will resolve your issue.