# 403 Web Parsing Error while parsing Web Content using Jsoup

Tags: java, web, jsoup, html-parsing

I have a task to parse through the contents of a website and store it in .fsv file in a local drive. I am using Jsoup to read the contents of the webpage and this is how my program looks like. For some reason, in Java I am getting a 403 Forbidden but I am getting the right results in web browsers.
Code:

```
String a ="https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/";
Document doc = soup.connect(a).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
                  
System.out.println("Title is ::: "+doc.title());
// System.out.println("Body is ::: "+doc.body().text());
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-left");
for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
    System.out.println("title is :::"+headline.attr("title")
        +" and url is ::::  "+ headline.absUrl("href"));
}
```

> Error:
> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=[https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/]

I have gone through some of the existing resolution for similar errors, but it did not helped.

Comment: Have you checked the site policy?

Comment: I tried using /robots.txt but it gave 404 resource not found error. Is there any other way we can check the policy?

Comment: If [`userAgent`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjsoup%5D+403) is ineffective, try some other request attributes, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37135114/230513), or [ask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) the owner.